# install MySQLdb to run in Pydev on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: python, macos, pydev, 32-bit, mysql-python

I had been stuck in some incompatible conflicts while trying to install mysql-python in Mac OS X 10.8 for a few days. After looking at some forums I found the solution to force Python run in 32 bit because mysql-python (MySQLdb) only has the 32 bit version:

`export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes`

That command helped to run MySQLdb in Terminal well. However when I installed PyDev, and tried to run a simple program with only one code line:`import MySQLdb`. I got the same error like when I run that in Terminal before forcing Python to run in 32 bit: 
`....mach-o, but wrong architecture`

I guess PyDev still picked the 64-bit python. How can I force PyDev run Python 32 bit?

In the folder `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` There is no 32-bit python. I have tried to install another python that have 32/64 bit Python (I couldn't find the python that have 32bit only for my Mac) but didn't know how to make Mac OS X pick the new 32 bit Python so that I can install mysql-python with that.

Is there any idea to help with this issue?